# Reactjs animation lag

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation

When spinning the wheel (animating a set of divs) a weird "load" is happening during the animation.
[Video showing the lag](https://gyazo.com/42b5db647faa62bf4d4c04e70e481afd)

We are spinning the wheel with this code:

```
document.getElementById('spinner').style.transform = `translate3d(${-(1680 * 4 - this.winnerPosition[ticket] * 112 + offset)}px, 0px, 0px)`;
    document.getElementById('spinner').style.transitionTimingFunction = `cubic-bezier(0.12, 0.8, 0.38, 1)`;
    document.getElementById('spinner').style.transitionDuration = `${time / 1000}s`;
```

There is a about 90 divs lined up that we just move using the translat3d function.
Looking at the performance capture by Google Chrome this is what we get: [Performance capture](https://gyazo.com/ab9be4363e6572c658f7cfff33204e01)

What could be the cause and fix for this?

Comment: React and `document.getElementById()` is a recipe for disaster

Comment: @TJ Interesting, do you know something else I can try?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing or why you're doing `document.getElementById` with React like this based on a video. Please see [mcve]